# Merge [video-conversion] → [video-converter]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[video-conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-conversion) (x13) needs to be merged into → [video-converter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-converter) (x94), and a synonym needs to be created.

I would actually propose to do it the other way round, focusing on the "conversion" rather than a single "converter" (piece of software). What do you think? (Please comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merged [video-converter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-converter) into [video-conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-conversion) - as the latter tag covers all things converting, not just video conversion software, but formats, containers, etc.

> updating post history, 120 rows affected
>   updating posts, 104 rows affected
>   updating PostTags associations, 94 rows affected
>   removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
>   updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
>   tag remapping of [video-conversion] and [video-converter] complete!
>   remapping 0 synonyms
>   2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
>   Tag Synonym video-converter -> video-conversion was approved!